# NoClassDefFoundError for inner class

Tags: java, swing, noclassdeffounderror

So, I've discovered that this is a very common problem for new Java programmers. Yet today is the first time I've run into it, after eight months of programming in Java.

This program has been working perfectly well for quite some time now. I made a minor tweak to the Swing layout last night and finally had a chance to give it a try this morning when I got that error. The tweak I made *could* un-made, but I am fairly certain it is unrelated to this error.

The error tells me that it occurs at the line:

```
private CheckTreeTableSelectionListener selectionListener = new CheckTreeTableSelectionListener();
```

which resides in the field list at the top of the class. Here's the interesting bit: `CheckTreeTableSelectionListener` is ***an inner class***. It is *not* external nor being imported. Also, I *did not touch* that inner class last night, nor did I touch the field that creates a new instance of it. Now I understand (barely) that the NoClassDefFoundError message means that the class definition could be found at compile-time, but not at runtime. This does not really help. If it is an inner class, how can it not be found? It's right there, inside the class that instantiates it!

### Edit

As requested, here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info/chrismcgee/sky/Scheduling$CheckTreeTableSelectionListener
at info.chrismcgee.sky.Scheduling.<init>(Scheduling.java:165)
at info.chrismcgee.sky.Scheduling$2.run(Scheduling.java:204)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.chrismcgee.sky.Scheduling$CheckTreeTableSelectionListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you show the whole stacktrace and the code please?

Comment: If you run into NoClassDefFound firsth thing you should check is there are such class in you classpath?

Comment: @Jens: Very well, you asked for it. I will edit the original post in a moment.

Comment: @talex: It's an inner class. How can an inner class _not_ be in the classpath?

Comment: @Sturm, be sure to check that your build process does not remove certain files, yes, this has happened to me

Comment: "the NoClassDefFoundError message means that the class definition could be found at compile-time, but not at runtime" -- it's the opposite. Since Java is dynamic, it can search for classes in runtime even if it's not available during compile-time.

Comment: @Sturm Inner class is separate class file with name someting like `OuterClassName$InnerClassName.class` located in same package as outer class

Comment: are there any static initializer blocks inside `CheckTreeTableSelectionListener`?

Comment: @epoch: I am not sure what mean by my "build process" removing certain files.

Comment: @Sturm, in terms of actual making an executable of your program, sometimes there may be a pre-post processor doing funny things

Comment: @epoch: I do not see any static fields or whatnot inside `CheckTreeTableSelectionListener`. There is one field and it is non-static.

Comment: look through your, jar/build-dir and see if you can actually find the class file

Comment: In my project folder, under /bin/info/chrismcgee/sky, I see 30 files: Scheduling.class and Scheduling$1.class through Scheduling$29.class. Why are there so many files?

Comment: @Sturm Scheduling$1.class is anonymous inner class. This mean that you have 29 of them.

Comment: If it really would help to see the entire file, I've put it up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CfGwQC7R).

Comment: @talex: Okay, that would make sense if they also include the anonymous inner classes that I have, which is quite a few.

Comment: @Sturm as far as I understand there are no `info/chrismcgee/sky/Scheduling$CheckTreeTableSelectionListener.class` file. Now we need to find out why. How you build you project? Is full rebuild help?

Comment: Okay, @talex, that's starting to make some sense. Although I still don't quite understand why it was working yesterday and not today. Anyway, I'm using Eclipse Kepler. What do you mean by a "full rebuild?"

Comment: @Sturm I dont remember exactly but in menu `Project` there is item `Clean`. Or something like this. If you use autobuild.

Comment: @talex and epoch, you guys are gods! Yes, there is a `Clean…` entry in the `Project` menu, and that created the .class files that it needed! When you mentioned 'full rebuild,' I began looking for some way to do so in Eclipse and was about to try that `Clean…` option when you posted to do the same.

Please post your answer so I can officially accept it as the answer to my question. And thanks again! You've saved my hide and I owe you! :~)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse IDE sometime some class magically disappear. You can try Project -> Clean to rebuild all.

Comment: Same in IntelliJ IDEA. Clean and rebuild the project solved the same problem for me.